# Excel Process in c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-2013, excel-interop

I have a problem in excel process ID killing im using Excel InterOp

first situation, when i was opening excel file while my program was accessing the data in Excel  , the process that i open the excel file was the same process of the program accessed. so when i kill the process ID , the other excel that i opened while using program will be killed to.

second situation, if i wouldn't kill the excel process ID, When i try to using the process that opened by the user before my program access , When my program working if the user close the excel my program will terminate to.

is there a method to use the new process and limited only my workbook to use, if other excel have open how can i let them to open by another process?

this my code ,

```
        public static void getExceltable()
       {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application m_app;
        m_app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        m_app.DisplayAlerts = false;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        string filename = Core.Class1.importPath;
        Workbook workbook=m_app.Workbooks.Open(filename,Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing
        ,Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        Worksheet sheet = m_app.Sheets[1];

         //// My Excel Process ////
       workbook.Close();
       int id;
       GetWindowThreadProcessId(m_app.Hwnd, out id);
       Process excelProcess = Process.GetProcessById(id);
       m_app.Quit();
       excelProcess.Kill();
       }
```

Comment: Excel interop is messy.  Consider using http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: Could u give me some more information about epplus plz ;D @EricJ.

Comment: i updated my code now , please give me some more comment @jstreet

Answer (score 1):

You should release **each** object associated with interop before exiting child office process. It is so painful, so I would recommend you to find alternative solutions.